# Installing PJSIP python lib with YOCTO

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am trying to install PJSIP on Yocto but I have some problems...
This is my [recipe](https://pastebin.com/uc8Yz91s). 
And the problems I have are :

1. Sometimes Yocto seems to compile without taking note of my layer and sometimes yes... 
   I do have added my layer in the bblayers file because sometimes the changes I do in my recipe are in my image but most of the time not...
2. For installing the python library of PJSIP we have to do `make` or
   `python setup.py install` in the `pjsip-apps/src/python/` folder.
   Why this in the recip:

   ```
   cd ${S}/pjsip-apps/src/python
   oe_runmake
   ```

   It's not working? (I say so because if I do `python --> import pjsua`
   on the target it's not working) How can I install it without doing
   it by hand after : 
   `cp -r ${S}/pjsip-apps/src/python/* ${D}/usr/pjsip-python --no-preserve=ownership`
    in the recip ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you checked the correct files are getting  packaged (see e.g. $WORKDIR/packages-split/)?  Have you added the package to your image?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I have added my package to my image. I did a clean compile of my yocto and I don't have the first problem anymore.